Angular 14 - To test method public date in Jest
I need to test this public method of my Angular component in Jest:
  getMinDateIniPicker(): Date {
    const dataControl = this.form.get(CATALOG_INPUT.DATA) as AbstractControl;
    this.createActivityService.addDataValidation(dataControl, this.contractDateIni);
    const minDate = new Date(this.contractDateIni) || new Date();
    if (dataControl.valid) {
      const initDate = new Date(dataControl.value);
      if (initDate > minDate) {
        minDate.setDate(initDate.getDate());
        minDate.setMonth(initDate.getMonth());
        minDate.setFullYear(initDate.getFullYear());
      }
    }
    return minDate;
  }

This is the html where the public method that is used to load a date in the selector by default:
      <div class="datepicker-content">
      <input class="cc-form-input" attr.aria-invalid="{{!!(submitted && form.get(CATALOG_INPUT.DATA)?.invalid)}}" attr.aria-describedby="{{CATALOG_INPUT.DATA + '-error'}}" [ngClass]="{'datepicker-invalid' : submitted && form.get(CATALOG_INPUT.DATA)?.invalid}" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="getMinDateIniPicker()" [formControlName]="CATALOG_INPUT.DATA" [id]="CATALOG_INPUT.DATA" [name]="CATALOG_INPUT.DATA">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
        <svg class="icon" matDatepickerToggleIcon width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path />
        </svg>
      </mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </div>

The most difficult part is contractDateIni, which is a private attribute that is obtained elsewhere in the code, but if it is empty should be able to test at least when value is: new Date()
My test:
describe('getMinDateIniPicker', () => {
    it('should return the minimum date for the picker', () => {
      const mockDate = new Date('2024-04-01');

      component.form = new FormGroup({
        [CATALOG_INPUT.DATA]: new FormControl(mockDate)
      });

      const minDate = component.getMinDateIniPicker();

      expect(minDate).toEqual(new Date('2024-04-01'));
    });
  });

Error:
  Expected: 2024-04-01T00:00:00.000Z
    Received: Date { NaN }

      565 |       const minDate = component.getMinDateIniPicker();
      566 |
    > 567 |       expect(minDate).toEqual(new Date('2024-04-01'));
          |                       ^
      568 |     });
      569 |   });
      570 |

Any suggestions on how I can do the test?
